# What is the difference between "Step Into" and "Force Step Into" in the IntelliJ IDEA debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

What is the difference between step into and force step into in debugging?

Comment: Did you check [the docs?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#force-step-into

Comment: I don't support all these downvotes based on it being a bad question.  On the other hand, if it's a duplicate, then someone should hammer it shut now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From my own observation using the IntelliJ debugger over the years, if you try to step into a method call on a given line of code, the following will happen:

- if the code being called be your *own* code, then the debugger will step into that method
- if the code being called be some third party library, then the debugger will ignore your request, and instead step over that line

By telling IntelliJ to force step into a line, in the case of a third party method, it will then try to find source code for that method.  If it *can't* find source code, then it might show you an auto generated stub based on the byte code/library.  But, there may not be any code shown, or if there is, it would be IntelliJ's best guess based on byte code.